# Error : Class A uses Class B, which is being defined

Tags: visual-c++, compilation, header, managed-c++

I have a C++ project that I've successfully wrapped with .NET classes using C++/CLI. I'm defining the wrapper classes in a `.h` file.

I'm currently getting `Error C2460: Mixer uses Track, which is being defined`.

As you can see in the code below, Mixer uses Track in the var `MainTrack` and Track also uses Mixer in the var `Parent`. How do I get these 2 classes linked to each other and compile successfully?

```
#ifndef CPP_MIXER_NET_H
#define CPP_MIXER_NET_H


#pragma managed



// Mixer class
public ref class Mixer {
private:
    void Create();
    void Destroy();

public:

    // props
    Track MainTrack;

    Mixer();
    ~Mixer();
    !Mixer();

};


// Track class
public ref class Track {
private:
    void Create(Track^ parent);
    void Destroy();


public:

    // props
    Mixer Parent;
    Track Parent;

    // public constructor
    Track(Track^ parent);
    ~Track();
    !Track();

};



#endif
```

Comment: Perhaps Mixer^ Parent? And Track^ Track. That or rethink your designer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare your classes at the very top:

```
public class Mixer;
public class Track;
```

Comment: "declare" = "foward declare"

Comment: I had to use the same signature, ie. `public ref class Mixer;`