# Constructor using itself while being defined error

Tags: c++, constructor

Error   1   error C2460: 'Square::string' : uses 'Square', which is being defined

Hello everyone, I am getting the following error while trying to implement my 4-square cipher. I have two constructors in the Square header and .cpp file. One of them takes no parameters while the other is taking a string. The one with the string is throwing the error.

square.h

```
#include <string>

#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H
class Square
{
public:
    Square();
    Square(string);
    ~Square();
    char mat[5][5];
    bool used[25];
    char getChar(int, int);
    int* getPos(char);

};

#endif
```

Here is the layout of it in the .cpp file.

```
Square::Square(string s)
{
//Code in here can show on request!
}
```

I think the string piece has something to do with it but I am not sure.

Comment: @harper: Compiles fine? Where is `string` defined then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Square( string );
```

you need

```
Square( std::string );
```

There may be other errors in the code not shown.

---

Not an error, but usually a `std::string` is passed by reference, to avoid needless copying.

---

Also, tip: with modern compilers, instead of include guards you can just use `#pragma once`. Keeping in mind that it's a universally supported *de facto* standard, not part of the official standard. I find it cleaner, somehow, and it alleviates the need to come up with distinct, unique include guard symbols.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough to really know what's going on here.  Everything looks fine from what you have.

Maybe you need the namespace?

```
Square(std::string);
```

Answer (score 0):

See (here on so: [Error : Class A uses Class B, which is being defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611547/error-class-a-uses-class-b-which-is-being-defined)) and also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kf0205c.aspx).

string is the problem. It's from std namespace so prefix every occurrence of string with 'std::', e.g. for your header:

```
#include <string>

#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H
class Square
{
public:
    Square();
    Square(std::string);
    ~Square();
    char mat[5][5];
    bool used[25];
    char getChar(int, int);
    int* getPos(char);

};
```